# Achieving UI/logic separation when the logic requires callback functions

Tags: javascript, callback, google-chrome-app

As far as I understand, in good practice, the UI code should invoke the logic whenever needed, but the logic should know nothing about the GUI ("loose coupling", see for example [How can I separate the user interface from the business logic while still maintaining efficiency?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127245/how-can-i-separate-the-user-interface-from-the-business-logic-while-still-mainta/127290#127290.)).

I am currently writing a chrome web app that uses the `chrome.serial` api. Most functions from this api are non-blocking and instead invoke a callback function when their work is done. For example

```
chrome.serial.getDevices(callback)
```

searches for devices and than calls `callback` with a list of found devices.

Now, after `chrome.serial.getDevices` is called from the logic part of my code, its results ultimately have  to be communicated back to the UI code.

How do I achieve clean UI/logic separation in this case? Does my UI need to register callback funcions with my logic code for every call it makes? That seems to violate the above principle of loose coupling and feels like it becomes very confusing very quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Initiate them in your controller code and pass them to the view. The view will then call its `.then()` method and display the result.

For example:

```
//controller.js
myAsyncTask = new Promise(resolve,reject=>{
   chrome.serial.getDevices(resolve)
})
view(myAsyncTask);

//view.js
function view(myAsyncTask){
   myAsyncTask.then(render);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using build tools, such as Webpack or Browserify, then you can have your "logic object" extend Node's `EventEmitter` (there are other implementations that work in-browser, such as https://github.com/Olical/EventEmitter, if you don't want to bundle Node APIs in with a build tool).

Your "logic object", which is a specialized EventEmitter, operates the chrome async API, which contacts the serial devices, then processing the results according to your data layer rules, and then emits its own events when it has something useful for the UI.

The UI listens both listens to, and emits, events on your "logic object", depending on what's happening.  Bonus: this event emitter can also be used by separate UI objects to communicate to each other, via events.

EventEmitter is the key that will make this kind of separation feel clean, simple, and extendable.